# How does move semantics apply on the following snippet when no xvalue is present?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I stumbled upon the [following article](https://lemire.me/blog/2012/11/26/why-i-like-the-new-c/) and do not understand the performance difference between C++98 and C++11 that is, as the author says, attributed to move semantics.

```cpp
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<vector<int> > V;

    for(int k = 0; k < 100000; ++k) {
        vector<int> x(1000);
        V.push_back(x);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

To the best of my knowledge, `V.push_back(x)` does not invoke any move semantics. I believe that the `x` is an lvalue and this snippet is invoking the same `vector::push_back(const T&)` in both C++98 and C++11.

The code compiles identically on either version: https://godbolt.org/z/q3Lzae

Is the author incorrect with his statement, or is the compiler smart enough to realize `x` is about to be destroyed?

If the author is incorrect, is there anything else present in C++11 that would have given this the performance boost "without changing a line of code"?

Comment: For full performance benefit, it should be `V.push_back(std::move(x))`. Given that the referenced article is old, I would think that the article is incorrect.

Comment: Or compounding the lines to `V.push_back(vector<int>(1000));` would ensure the temporary is recognised as such. In theory you would get better performance using `V.emplace_back(1000);`, but that syntactic sugar might postdate the article, so `V.emplace(V.end(),1000);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct that object `x` won't be moved from. The move operations gaining performance have to do with the other `k` vectors already in `V`.

As a vector grows (unless `reserve` was used with a sufficient size), it will sometimes need to reallocate to get a bigger chunk of memory, since its elements are required to be in contiguous memory. This doesn't happen on every `push_back`, but it will certainly happen sometimes in this example. So let's say `push_back` and other functions make use of some private function `grow_capacity`, which gets enough memory, and then creates objects already in the vector within that memory.

In C++03, the only reasonable way to create the objects in the new memory, for an arbitrary template parameter `T`, is using the copy constructor of `T`.

```
// C++03 implementation?
template <typename T, typename Alloc>
std::vector<T, Alloc>::grow_capacity(::std::size_t new_capacity)
{
    T* new_data = get_allocator().allocate(new_capacity);
    T* new_end = new_data;
    try {
        for (const_iterator iter = begin(); iter != end(); ++iter) {
            ::new(static_cast<void*>(new_end)) T(*iter); // T copy ctor!
            ++new_end;
        }
    } catch (...) {
        while (new_end != new_data) (--new_end)->~T();
        get_allocator().deallocate(new_data, new_capacity);
        throw;
    }

    // Clean up old objects and memory.
    for (const_reverse_iterator riter = rbegin(); riter != rend(); ++riter)
        riter->~T();
    get_allocator().deallocate(_data, _capacity);

    // Assign private members.
    _data = new_data;
    _capacity = new_capacity;
}
```

In C++11 and later, when `std::vector<T>` needs to reallocate to a larger capacity, it is allowed to move its `T` elements instead of copying them if it can do so without breaking the strong exception guarantee. This requires that the move constructor is declared to not throw any exceptions. But if the move constructor might throw, the elements need to be copied in the old way, to make sure the vector will remain in a consistent state if that happens.

```
// C++17 implementation?
template <typename T, typename Alloc>
std::vector<T, Alloc>::grow_capacity(::std::size_t new_capacity)
{
    T* new_data = get_allocator().allocate(new_capacity);

    if constexpr (::std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<T>) {
        ::std::uninitialized_move(begin(), end(), new_data);   // T move ctor!
    } else {
        T* new_end = new_data;
        try {
            for (const T& old_obj : *this) {
                ::new(static_cast<void*>(new_end)) T(old_obj); // T copy ctor!
                ++new_end;
            }
        } catch (...) {
            while (new_end != new_data) (--new_end)->~T();
            get_allocator().deallocate(new_data, new_capacity);
            throw;
        }
    }

    for (const_reverse_iterator riter = rbegin(); riter != rend(); ++riter)
        riter->~T();
    get_allocator().deallocate(_data, _capacity);

    // Assign private members.
    _data = new_data;
    _capacity = new_capacity;
}
```

So in the container with type `std::vector<std::vector<int> >`, `T` is `std::vector<int>`. Growing the capacity the C++03 way will sometimes require a large number of copy constructors then destructors for the `std::vector<int>`. Each copy constructor allocates some memory and copies 1000 `int` values, and each destructor deallocates some memory, so this will really add up. But with the C++11 `std::vector`, since the element type `std::vector<int>` does have a `noexcept` move constructor, the `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` container can just use that move constructor, which is just a few swaps of scalar members and also causes the destructors of the moved-from old objects to do nothing.

Comment: I was in the middle of writing words that are pretty much equivalent to this answer when this answer was posted.  Instead of finishing my post, I'm taking the easy way out and upvoting. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

What's going on in this example is that `x` is about to go out of scope in the push_back call (its the end of its lifetime, and there is no subsequent use), so the compiler *may* treat it as an xvalue and move out of it.  Its not one of the cases where the compiler is required to do a move optimization, so it might not, but any decent compiler will if optimization is enabled (both gcc and clang will use a move here).

Comment: Changing a function call from `push_back(const value_type&)` to `push_back(value_type&&)` is not in any circumstances allowed by the Standard. Can you back up "both gcc and clang will use a move here"?

Comment: If you compile the above code, compile it with optimizations, you'll see that move semantics are being used -- the memory for the nested vectors are only allocated once and moved into the enclosing vector -- no deallocation of temp vectors occurs.

Comment: That's not what I see in https://godbolt.org/z/VzskZg : In the case of no reallocation of `V`, clang allocates for `x` at line 23 and for the appended `V` element at line 40, and gcc allocates for `x` at line 315 and for the appended `V` element at line 336.